# How to Pass "reloadOnSearch: false" parameter with ui-sref-opts

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have following state configuration:

```
.state('test', {
                    url: '/info',
                    templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
                    // reloadOnSearch:false
                })
```

I do not want to enable reloadOnSearch = false in state confiugration. Because this way it will not allow user to change the URL and see new data. So I want to pass this parameter along with ui-sref-opts.

I tried enough searching on internet but that doesn;t seems to be working:

Here is my HTML:

```
<tab ui-sref="test" ui-sref-active="active" active="testingState">
.......
</tab>
```

I tried to pass, "reloadOnSearch: false" with ui-sref-opts but that doesn't seems to be working.

Can any one please help me here.

Answer (score 1):

I recall having to do this a while ago in order to save browser history anytime a search was made / filtered. I found the post that I used which helped me solve the problem, although it's a bit jankey (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1079):

```
//set the reloadOnSearch on state to false initially in some code block
$state.current.reloadOnSearch = false;

// update query string here
$location.search({"from": 1, "to": 2});

//revert reloadOnSearch on the state!
$timeout(function () {
    $state.current.reloadOnSearch = undefined;
});
```

I believe you should be able to place this code in whatever is causing the page to refresh.